# split and sort array into multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I have a 2d array of double values and I want to split it into a bunch of arrays based on a value in the array
For instance, if I had:

```
{2, 0.0},
{3, 0.0},
{1, 0.0},
{2, 1.0},
{5, 0.0},
{7, 1.0},
{6, 2.0}
```

I want to split this into arrays like this

```
{0.0, 2, 3, 1, 5}
{1.0, 2, 7}
{2.0, 6}
```

The arrays I am dealing with may contain several hundred lines, so it would be faster to iterate through each of these lists than checking the full array, and if the second column is the same doing something

for example, iterating through the first list takes 7*6/2 = 21 comparisons

iterating through the second lists takes 7 to split it up, and 7 comparisons of everything inside the lists ie. {2/3, 2/1, 2/5. 3/1, 3/5, 1/5}, {2,7}, {}

How would I go about doing something like this, or is there a better way of comparing them?

Comment: So, are you entirely attached to arrays? Would you be willing to move to another sort of data structure? If so, then a Dictionary would be perfect for this situation, as they are designed for this use case

Comment: I'm not really attached to arrays, but I do like the performance they give, what is a dictionary like?

Comment: For retrieval, O(1). Heck even a map with the values being type ArrayList would work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be just one iteration by using `HashMap` ...

**Algo**

1) traverse each row of 2D array

2) `myHashMap.add(arr[i][1], arr[i][0]) // add(key,value)`

3) repeat

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a 2D array, I'd recommend using another data structure like HashMap, or HashTable: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html.

These will allow for faster searches and easier code.

Example of how your map could look:

```
HashMap map = new HasMap<Double, ArrayList<Integer>>(); //key is the 0.0, 2.0, whatever, and the value mapped is an array of integers that have those values. (2, 3, 1, 5 for 0.0)
```

However, importing it may take a little time, but after you have it all set up, you can do something like this to update the values. Say you want to add 10 which had 0.0 as it's value:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = map.get(0.0);
array.add(10);
map.put(0.0, array); //replaces the old value with the updated array.
```